# Partial won't render when replacing html with jQuery and escape_javascript

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3

When the user is clicking on a link with the class "edit_resource", the content of a div should be replaced by a partial. Here is my code:

```
$(".edit_resource").click(function(){
  var id = $(this).attr("id")
  $('#id' + id + '_show').html("<%= escape_javascript(render :partial => 'form', :locals => {:@resource => resource})%>")
})
```

The code is working as expected, except that that escape_javascript doesn't work. The new content of the div is the text

> <%= escape_javascript(render :partial => 'form', :locals => {:@resource => resource})%>

, and this is also what is shown on the page.

No code is executed, and my partial isn't rendered. I have tried to use <%== instead of <%= without luck.

I have also tried

> <%= raw escape_javascript(render :partial => 'form', :locals => {:@resource => resource})%>

I have even tried to replace the partial part of the code with just simple rails code. That didn't help either.

What can I do?

I use Rails 3.0.10, and my javascript_include_tag is like this:

> <%= javascript_include_tag 'jquery-1.6.2.min', 'jquery-ui-1.8.16.custom.min', 'application', 'jquery.rails.js'%>

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have put my js in a js.erb-file, and finally managed to use my variables in the right way.

Here's my code:

```
$('#id' + '<%= @id %>' + '_show').html('<%= escape_javascript(raw render :partial => 'form', :locals => {:@resource => Resource.find_by_id(@id)}).html_safe %>')
```

And in the controller:
format.js   { @id = params[:id]}

In the view: <%= link_to t('edit'), resources_path(:id => resource.id), :remote => true %>

Answer (score 3):

Add .html_safe after the closing bracket of escape_javascript

Comment: Didn't help... Thank's for your reply.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you can have :@resource @ followed by an symbol :

```
<%= escape_javascript(render :partial => 'form', :locals => {:@resource => resource})%>
```

Just take that @ out

```
<%= escape_javascript(render :partial => 'form', :locals => {:resource => resource})%>
```

and use the variable by calling
`resource` in your partial

Comment: Thanks for your reply! Using :@resource works very well in a non-ajax variant I have used for testing. I have nevertheless tried to change this according to your advise, but it didn't help. If :@resource was the problem, I think I would have got an error message. The only thing I get is the whole escape-thing as a string on my page